# Huge sheet with many succesive A3

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I've created a new blank diagram with A3 format, but after starting to draw my A3 sheet is **increased N times** to the left and right (see the scrollbars!). How can i return back to the A3 sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When something similar happened to me I discovered that somehow some very long random lines spanning numerous pages had appeared.

One workaround I used for my problem was to select everything I wanted, copy it and paste it into a fresh document.

A second solution that worked for me was to scroll to the distant edge and then drag to select the rogue lines so that I could delete them.

The third solution I attempted was to go into Options:Advanced:Edit and search for items with a ridiculously large geometry. My rogue items had an mxPoint set as `x="703100"` I deleted the three rogue mxcell details and all was fine.

Needless to say, I cannot guarantee your problem is the same one that I had.

Comment: Solved with last solution! I had two mxcell with huge value. 10x ;-)